# Facebook Android Login GraphAPI - how to get users age_range? (max & min)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have no problem getting all of the other information given to me using the "public_profile" scope. Stuck on getting age range. Also, to be clear I am not looking for "user_birthday" only the "age_range". Thank you.

```
 // set permission list, Don't foeget to add email
authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email"));
        // session state call back event

        Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                    Exception exception) {
                onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
                if (session.isOpened()) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Access Token" + session.getAccessToken());
                    Request.newMeRequest(session,
                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                // callback after Graph API response with user
                                // object
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                        Response response) {
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        // fid = user.getId();
                                        // Log.i("ID", fid);
                                        femail = user.asMap().get("email")
                                                .toString();
                                        Log.i("email", femail);

                                        ffirstname = user.getFirstName();
                                        Log.i("firstname", ffirstname);


                            }
                        }).executeAsync();
```

Comment: Reference-> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this @JSON?  Am stuck with the same problem.